# Queuing html functions

Tags: jquery

I want to change the content of a div 3 times, with a delay of 1 second between each change.
`delay()` doesn't work in this code :

```
$('#import-status-msg').html('Importing content ..').delay(1000).
html('Organizing content ..').delay(1000).
html('Eating burrito ..');
```

I get 'Eating burrito' directly. What's the shortest way to get this done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a more general solution, using jquery's [`queue`](http://api.jquery.com/queue/) function:

```
var gen = function (str, delay) {
  return function (n) {
    $(this).html(str);
    setTimeout(n, delay || 1000);
  };
};

$('#import-status-msg').queue([
  gen('Importing content ..'),
  gen('Organizing content ..'),
  gen('Eating burrito ..')
]);
```

http://jsbin.com/oraler/1/

Comment: Can you explain whats happening in the setTimeout function line here?

Comment: using queue, the callbacks will be called with a *next*-function (the `n` parameter). This function will either do nothing  (end of queue) or call the next callback in the queue. `setTimeout` is just do delay moving to the next cb in the queue.

Comment: Thanks, its very comprehensive and educative!

Answer (score 2):

Using the setTimeout-function:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    $('#import-status-msg').html('Importing content ..');
    setTimeout(function() {
        $('#import-status-msg').html('Organizing content ..');
        setTimeout(function() {
            $('#import-status-msg').html('Eating burrito ..');
        }, 1000);
    }, 1000);
}, 1000);
```

You can't use jQuery's delay()-function as that only has an effect on the standard effects queue eg. animations.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
setTimeout(function(){},1000)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var q = ['Importing content ..','Organizing content ..','Eating burrito ..'];
$("#test").html(q[0]);
var i = 1;
var p = setInterval(function(){
    $("#test").html(q[i]);
    i++;
    if(i==q.length){
        clearInterval(p);
    }
},1000);
```

**[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZpWTT/)**